# Initialising Enum members using Spring

Tags: spring, enums, initialization

I have and Enum like below.

public enum MyEnum {

```
ENUM1("ENUM1Code", "ENUM1 Desc"), ENUM2("ENUM2Code", "ENUM2"), ENUM3("ENUM3Code", "ENUM3");

private String code;
private String description;
private MyEnum(String code, String description) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
}
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

}

Can anybody suggest me how to remove the initialisation from this Enum and perform it through Spring ?

Thanks in advance

Dileep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because enum are static objects.
You can externalize code/description and manage them manually.

EDIT:
I can't see need to use Spring for this type of jobs; you can achieve the same goal with easy code (a bit of Spring is used, the `PropertiesLoaderUtils` utility class).
Create a properties file where you store, for every enum, code and description and write utility code to read data; result of your custom code is a UDT like that:

```
class EnumWithData implements Serializable {
  MyEnum enumValue;
  String code;
  String description;

  //  Write properties get/set

  //  Equals check for enumValue only
  boolean equals(Object other) {
    EnumWithData b = (EnumWithData)other;
    return b.enumValue == this.enumValue;
  }
}

abstract class EnumWithDataUtility {
  private static Properties definition = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties("path/to/resource");

  public final static EnumWithData getEnumWithData(MyEnum enumValue) {
    EnumWithData udt = new EnumWithData();
    udt.enumValue = enumValue;
    ...
    return udt;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, could you please clarify what you mean by externalize? using spring how can we do that ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luca Basso Ricci, will try this